# Уменьшить размер изображения

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Изображение, которое отправляется, допустим 1600x800 пикселе, с нашего сервера на html страницу - отправляется как файл 1600x800 и уж потом благодаря CSS обретает размеры 600x800, 432x222 и т.д.

Как сделать так, чтобы сервер "уменьшал изображение" до нужного в CSS и присылал на сервер изображение нужного размера?

Вопрос возник после любопытной проверки страницы сайта через `www.gtmetrix.com` и `PageSpeed Insight`,  где мне писали на каждом из них `https://***.jpg s resized in HTML or CSS from 1600x800 to 255x127. Serving a scaled image could save 43.0KiB (97% reduction).` и т.д.

> Ответ с изменением изображения вручную не принимается. Стоит
>   представить, что если надо выгрузить на страницу 1000 картинок. Каждую
>   из них не сможешь отредактировать

Comment: может gzip настроить  ?

Comment: @НикитаФаст это сжимание самого изоражение.  А я про уменьшение самого размера)

Comment: тогда ffmpeg почитайте в сети как им пользоваться, сработает если хостинг не shared

Comment: Инструмент для обработки изображений — ImageMagick, а не ffmpeg. Для него есть и php'шный плагин. А вот _когда_ его вызывать — смотрите по обстоятельствам.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev imageMagick использует ffmpeg ....

Comment: @НикитаФаст он и curl использует, но это не делает его инструментом для скачивания файлов. Работать с изображениями он прекрасно может безо всяких ffmpeg'ов. ffmpeg — инструмент для обработки видео.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev  да да точно ..прошу прощения ... но я им фотки тоже обрабатывал но в линуксе

Comment: @НикитаФаст настоящие мастера умеют сверлить лобзиком и пилить дрелью, не вопрос :)

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev  я в смысле слайдшоу делал ...

Comment: @НикитаФаст а, ну тогда ffmpeg, разумеется. Как частный случай видео.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сделать так, чтобы в html-коде при запросе картинки серверу передавались ее размеры, например:
`<img src="//site.com/img/image.jpg?w=432&h=222">`
Далее нужно для папки `site.com/img` настроить `.htaccess` (или что-то иное, в зависимости от сервера) так, чтобы любом обращении к этой папке запускался скрипт, задача которого распарсить запрос к серверу и запустить некий софт или плагин (не знаю в какой форме они существуют), который выполнит ресайз вашей графики.
Общий принцип такой.

зы: Существует софт для десктопа, который может выполнять операции над графикой в пакетном режиме, т.ч. обработать по определенному правилу 1000 картинок - проблем нет. Для win это imbatch например. Другое дело, что одна и так же картинка лежит на сервере в нескольких размерах и жрет место...

Comment: Ужасы какие-то. И при каждом открытии страницы оно будет постоянно запускать скрипт на ресайз?

Comment: при каждом запросе графики в нужном размере. серверу будет сложновато, но вы что предлагаете?

Comment: Я предлагаю делать, как делает большинство - на сервере хранить все варианты и отдавать нужное.

Comment: Ну, автор попросил не предлагать такое. Хотя место наверно все же дешевле производительности. Можно дополнительно задействовать кеширование или ресайзнутый файл хранить определенное время после последнего запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Не самый лучший вариант, но пишется относительно быстро, сервер почти не нагружает и идеально подходит для тех мест, где картинки тянутся "автоматически" (каталоги, галереи, etc)

Создаете php обработчик для картинок и папку для складирования кешированных картинок

```
    public static function resizeImage($imgPath, $width, $height="")
    {
        //генерируйте имя картинки на свой вкус
        $path = "/path/to/cahched/image" . $width . "_" . $imgName;
        $fullPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $path;
        if (file_exists($fullPath))
        {
            return $path;
        }
        //Пишите логику резайза любым удобным вам способом
        return $path;
    }
```

Далее на страницу вставляете изображение таким способом:

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="<? resizeImage("/image.jpg", 300) ?>" media="(min-width: 600px)">
 <source srcset="<? resizeImage("/image.jpg", 600) ?>" media="(min-width: 900px)">
 <img src="/image.jpg" alt="MDN">
</picture>
```